# Android intel VT-x ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, haxm

I am running Ubuntu version 14.04.1 LTS in my Vmware-Player and I am trying to install HAXM by following this guide: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213272 , but after executing the command: egrep –c ‘(vmx|svm)’ /proc/cpuinfo, I am getting 0 as a result, which means that my CPU does not support hardware virtualization. But I have installed the Intel Processor Identification Utility and I am getting this picture (Don't have enough reputation yet, to post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUl4W.png

According to the picture above, my CPU supports virtualization technology. I also maked sure that VT-x is enabled in the BIOS. I have also tried the all options in the VMWare player settings wich are 1. Automatic, 2. Binary translation, Intel VT-x or AMD-V, 3. Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI

I have the following CPU: Intel Core i5 2500k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that the NX/XD disable bit was on? See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-exec-shield-protection-nx-bit-protection-sysctl/ 
And did you do a cold boot (complete power down and up) after changing the BIOS settings?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working now. I did not check if the NX/XD bit was on.